# tomcat 9 doesn't start

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

My environment is **Ubuntu 18.04** and I installed `tomcat` *version* **9**, but it doesn't start.

tomcat keeps restarting, I did a lot of search, but I don't know what is the reason.

This is my tomcat status.

---

```
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop) since Wed 2019-01-23 22:22:29 KST; 167ms ago
  Process: 7938 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7946 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS); Control PID: 7948 (catalina.sh)
    Tasks: 20 (limit: 2321)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
           ├─7947 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dja
           ├─7948 /bin/sh /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
           └─7958 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache

 1월 23 22:22:29 lee-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
 1월 23 22:22:29 lee-VirtualBox startup.sh[7938]: Tomcat started.
 1월 23 22:22:29 lee-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
 1월 23 22:22:29 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]: NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.tra
...skipping...
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop) since Wed 2019-01-23 22:22:29 KST; 167ms ago
  Process: 7938 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7946 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS); Control PID: 7948 (catalina.sh)
    Tasks: 20 (limit: 2321)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
           ├─7947 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dja
           ├─7948 /bin/sh /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
           └─7958 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache

 1월 23 22:22:29 lee-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
 1월 23 22:22:29 lee-VirtualBox startup.sh[7938]: Tomcat started.
 1월 23 22:22:29 lee-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
 1월 23 22:22:29 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]: NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.tra


● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop) since Wed 2019-01-23 22:22:29 KST; 3s ago
  Process: 7938 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7946 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS); Control PID: 7948 (catalina.sh)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 2321)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
           ├─7948 /bin/sh /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
           └─7989 sleep 1

 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:436)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:213)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:513)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:403)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]:         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:497)
 1월 23 22:22:31 lee-VirtualBox shutdown.sh[7948]: The stop command failed. Attempting to signal the process to stop through OS signal.
```

Comment: formatting fixed

Comment: Can you take a look at the catalina log and show whats there?